# Can we replace Async/Await with promises

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, async-await, testcafe

Can we use promises instead of async/await in below code?

---

```
fixture`MyFixture`.page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test("My first test", async t => {
  await t
    .typeText("#developer-name", "srikanth chitla")
    .setTestSpeed(0.1)
    .click("#submit-button");
});
```

---

Comment: Yes, in fact in your example you can remove `async / await`, and not even replace with promises, because that code above is saying `t` is already a promise.

Comment: Poor effort in your question.

Comment: Theoretically yes each method you chain returns a promise so you can do this t.typeText("....").then(returnValue => { ... }) but your code would be look more complicated.

Comment: If you use `async` / `await`, then you are already using promises!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use Promise chains instead of `async/await`, but this way is more verbose:

```
fixture`MyFixture`
    .page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test("My first test", t => {
  return t
    .typeText("#developer-name", "srikanth chitla")
    .then(() => t.setTestSpeed(0.1))
    .then(() => t.click("#submit-button"));
});
```

If you need to run tests with a Node.js version that doesn't support `async/await` natively, don't worry: TestCafe uses [Babel](https://babeljs.io) under the hood to transform ES6 features into the code that can be executed by any Node.js version.

Comment: Actually in this case the `then`s are not needed the await is on the whole thing.